# How to mock class used in separate namespace?

Tags: python, python-2.7, namespaces, mocking, python-unittest

Package Structure:

```
pqr/pq.py
test.py
```

`pqr/pq.py` has following structure

Where lmn is globally installed pip module

Structure of `pq.py`

```
from lmn import Lm

class Ab():

    def __init__(self):
        self.lm = Lm()

    def echo(self, msg):
        print msg
```

`test.py` has following structure

```
from pqr.pq import Ab
```

How to mock `Lm()` class over here so to test all method from Ab class?

Comment: Python supports Monkey-Patching. You can simply call `pqr.pq.Lm = your_mockup` and `Ab` will use `your_mockup` instead of the original `Lm`. (This answers your question, but it may not be the best pattern for testing. Consider modifying the constructor of `Ab` to allow to pass an alternative `Lm` implementation as an alternative.)

Comment: @Phillip thanks for your answer, but I didn't get it completely, can you give me a working code snippet of this, I am a newbie to the testing framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't really matter where `Lm` came from. You imported `Lm` into the `pqr.pq` namespace as a global *there*, so you'd only have replace that name there and nowhere else. That's because the `Ab.__init__` method will look for it 'locally' in it's own module.

So using the [`mock` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) all you need to do is patch the name `pqr.pq.Lm`:

```
import mock
from pqr.pq import Ab

with mock.patch('pqr.pq.Lm') as mock_lm:
    # within this block, `Lm` in the `pqr.pq` namespace has been replaced
    # by a mock object
    test_instance = Ab()
    # assert that the patch succeeded; .return_value is used because
    # Ab.__init__ *calls* Lm()
    assert test_instance.lm is mock_lm.return_value
```

Also see the [*Where to patch* section](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) of the `mock` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For testing, you can use the `mock` module (standard in newer python 3, downloadable from pypi for older versions) to create "fake" classes.  There is a great article on the mock library that explains how to do this, which I will link [here](https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python), that helped me a lot.  You will want your test.py file to look something like the code below.

```
from pqr import pq
import mock

class TestLm(unittest.Testcase):

    @mock.patch(pq.LM)
    def test_lm(self, mock_lm):
        my_ab = pq.AB()
        my_ab.echo()
```

Using the `mock` module, you can create a mock version of a module/class that you can use for testing methods, simply by "patching" it in with a decorator above your test method.  This replaces the original version of the specified module/class with a MagicMock object, that is then passed into the test method as a second argument.  This MagicMock does not actually execute any functionality of `Lm`, but allows you to make assertions about how it is supposed to work. You can override functionality later, should you need to.  However, there is a catch, which is explained in the guide I linked.  You need to make sure that you import `Lm` **from the module in which it is used, not in the traditional manner.**  For imports, Python creates module objects that are specific to the module they are imported into, so you need to mock the specific `Lm` object from the `pq` module in order to test its functionality.  The library is a little complicated to use at first, and contains far more information than is appropriate to cover in a single StackOverflow answer, so I would recommend doing some reading.

Documentation for the `mock` module can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html). 
The download for the Python 2.7 version can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock).

I am fairly new to the `mock` library myself, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong!

EDIT: Upon seeing Martijn's answer, I realized I forgot parenthesis in the my_ab constructor!